# Form Instantiation time in Restlet

Tags: rest, restlet

I am new to Restlet framework and I have the following time issue in the post method of my server resource.
My post method code

```
@Post
    public Representation represent(Representation entity){
        try{
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Form aForm = new Form(getRequestEntity());
            System.err.println("FORM Instantiation TIME: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new StringRepresentation("hello");
    }
```

On different trails, the output that I am getting is 1900-1999 ms. But if I uncomment the line Thread.sleep(1000), then the time output is 900-999 ms. Can any one please confirm what is happening when instantiation the Form object and why the time is always 1900+ ms. Sorting out this time issue is important for me as I have to implement token based authentication to reduce the post method processing time.

Comment: Could you provide details, such as the version of Restlet used, the HTTP connectors involved and especially the client-side details. Is it a local test and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. The restlet version I am using is 2.0.7
Here is the details

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Component component = new Component();
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182); 
        VirtualHost aHost = component.getDefaultHost();
        aHost.attach("/sample", new MyApplication());
        component.getLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
        component.start();
        System.err.println("REST SERVICE STARTED ON PORT NUMBER 8182...");
    }
```

I am running this application in local and not in any Web/App Server.